# Parse string to datetime format

Tags: powershell

I'm getting all installed software on my computer, and print result to a HTML table. But a lot of dates have `yyyyMMdd` format, but I would like `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Windows 10
Powershell version - 5.1.17

```bsh
$Soft = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*;
#$Soft64 =  Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*;
$InstallDate = $Soft | Select-Object InstallDate;

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $InstallDate.Length; $i++) {
    if ($InstallDate[$i] -match '-') {
        $InstallDate[$i]
    } else {
        $InstallDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($InstallDate[$i], 'yyyyMMdd', $null)
        $InstallDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    }
}
```

One date on list is with a good format (`2019-04-01`) or they are empty/null, and after execute script I'm getting this result:

```
InstallDate
-----------
2019-04-01
```

But dates which don't contain `-`, e.g. `20190319`, throw errors:

```
Cannot find an overload for "ParseExact" and the argument count: "3".
At C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\ForLoopTest.ps1:12 char:9
+         $InstallDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($InstallDate[$i], 'yyyy ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\ForLoopTest.ps1:13 char:9
+         $InstallDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: Use: `$InstallDate = $Soft | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InstallDate;`

Comment: After that I get ```Select-Object : Property "InstallDate" cannot be found.```

Comment: Yes, but only for the objects where the property doesn't exist. You wont't be able to parse them anyway. Your `$installDate` variable should have a list of the strings where the property *did* exist

Comment: Ok, but it only printed date wich have a yyyy-MM-dd format. Objects which installed date is empty are is few, but objects with yyyyMMdd format , they are not printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove empty `InstallDate` results from the data you're parsing, and then expand the property, as [@arco444 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846276/parse-string-to-datetime-format#comment98354705_55846276). Also, your loop currently assigns a parsed date back to the array variable over which your loop iterates, thus destroying all other values in that array.

Using `InvariantCulture` instead of `$null`, as [@Moerwald suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55846681/1630171), is recommended, but not the cause of the issue. Another (performance-)optimization would be using the `Contains()` string method instead of the `-match` operator.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
$reg = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

$Soft = Get-ItemProperty $reg
$InstallDate = $Soft |
               Where-Object { $_.InstallDate } |
               Select-Object -Expand InstallDate

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $InstallDate.Length; $i++) {
    if ($InstallDate[$i].Contains('-')) {
        $InstallDate[$i]
    } else {
        $d = [DateTime]::ParseExact($InstallDate[$i], 'yyyyMMdd', $culture)
        $d.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    }
}
```

Pipelining the entire processing is also a possibility:

```
$reg = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

Get-ItemProperty $reg | Where-Object {
    $_.InstallDate
} | Select-Object -Expand InstallDate | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Contains('-')) {
        $_
    } else {
        [DateTime]::ParseExact($_, 'yyyyMMdd', $culture).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a FormatProvider to specify culture when using `ParseExact`:

```
$dt = [datetime]::ParseExact("20190319", "yyyyMMdd", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
$dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
2019-03-19
```

`ParseExact` throws an exception, therefore `$InstallDate` is invalid and you call `ToString` on it. You can add an additional `$null` check:

```
 $dt = [datetime]::ParseExact("20190319", "yyyyMMdd", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
 if ($dt) {
   $dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
 }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried this. This work fine with date added manually like in your example, but not working if I have $InstallDate[$i]